# Sound Does Not Play On Collision Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

It happened to me before and now it is happening again, I tried to make the sound play in different ways but no result, The sound play only on Awake.

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public int speed = 5;
    public GameObject Particle;

    public AudioSource src; 

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            src.Play();
            Instantiate(Particle, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            src.Play();
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Instantiate(Particle, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        }
    }

  }
```

I have an audio Source added:

[image: Audio Source]

Comment: you missed the most important setting - youve set it to play on trigger not collision and you havent shown you set trigger

Comment: Oh,my bad, it is like that  becuase my boxcollider is having the On trigger box checked. how can I make it work in this case? @BugFinder

Comment: well we wont know what you did as you didnt share.  Are you meeting the unity collision requirements?

Comment: @BugFinder, I am still learning about it, but the object the script is attached to detects when it is colliding with the enemy or with the wall and is getting destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because when Bullet.cs call the OnTriggerEnter2D()... it also call Destory().
Let's see the method flow. When the cs call sound play and then also will call destory soon.
so... how to change? if you need the sound, just add the AudioSource component to particle prefab and import the bullet hit sound.(i think don't need a code, just check the option - play on Awake) the problem will be solve.

ps. I think you need to use object pool is better.
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling#
And need to use sound manger, (When unity so many call the sound source, the sound will turn into noise)

Comment: I was thinking about that but I though because I placed them in order so the sound goes first would run okay, what I did now is to access the audiosource from another GameObject in the scene but when I try to add it to the prefab is telling me Type missmatch, but there is the audioSource, If i place the prefab in the scene and attach the gameobject with the audioSource is working just right, but then I cannot initialize the bullet as I want, any clue?
Thank you!

Comment: Ordering is not important now. Important point is calling Destroy() method. When play sound, also called destory method to destory sound obj at time.  Cause of it the scene has no audio source, sound could not play.
 and When u use a particle prefab. just import a audio source component like a bullet obj. and Check a play awake option. so let's see the flow.

Comment: When Bullet collide to wall, destory at time and instantiate particle by the code. and particle is made, play the bullet hit sound because of audio source component(with check on play on awake option)